# How to debug the PayPal debug_id?

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-vault

We're using PayPal Vault Rest API for our payment features. It was working fine in sandbox, but it started giving us errors for a couple of weeks now. Error is manifesting in sandbox mode.

It's giving following error:

```json
{
    "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "message": "An internal service error occurred.",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "############"
}
```

So my question is how we can use `debug_id` to find out the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an ID you have to send to Paypal Merchant Support: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/utils/login_form?p_next_page=ask Also, be sure to check your Paypal.log (or whatever you named it) for more info on a request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From PayPal github issue tracker

[Debug ID](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/56)

You cannot use directly this id, you have to give it to the support.

On the other hand, if you [log into your developer account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox), you should be able to see all requests made to a certain applications and/or email addresses.

[image]

Requests with errors are shown with the orange sign. You can click to see more details.

Comment: What do you call a developer account? is it www.sandbox.paypal.com?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev This is the main account. When you register to developer.paypal.com, after that you can create as many sandbox accounts, as you like from the developer dashboard

Comment: @DilyanTrayanov just to clarify what Yevgeniy meant to assert is

You can't check any requests of Live PayPal application from the developer dashboard.  You can only get sandbox app request